# Unable to get second level retries working

Tags: masstransit

I'm using masstransit 4.0.30319, with rabbitmq 3.7.3 and I am having trouble getting second-level retries working.

The code below is a simple program to illustrate what I'm doing.

As far as I can tell from the documentation for masstransit, I think this should be working (console output should be a new line of "Received: Hi" every 10 seconds). But I just get one line of output.

I tried ScheduleSend(), SchedulePublish() and Redeliver(). All with the same results.

I'm very new to masstransit so I expect I am making some simple mistake somewhere...

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MassTransit;

namespace TestMassTransit2
{
    public class YourMessage { public string Text { get; set; } }
    public class YourMessageConsumer : IConsumer<YourMessage>
    {
        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<YourMessage> context)
        {
            await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Text}");

            //await context.ScheduleSend(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), context.Message);
            //await context.SchedulePublish(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), context.Message);
            await context.Redeliver(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            //await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"retry count: {context.GetRetryAttempt()}");
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
            {
                var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                {
                    h.Username("guest");
                    h.Password("guest");
                });

                sbc.UseMessageScheduler(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/quartz"));

                sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test_queue", ep =>
                {
                    ep.Consumer<YourMessageConsumer>();
                });
            });

            bus.Start();

            bus.Publish(new YourMessage { Text = "Hi" });

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            bus.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running an instance of Quartz on the `/quartz` endpoint?

Comment: Also, have you read the docs? http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/

Comment: Yes, I have read the docs on Scheduling. But I guess I'm not running an instance of Quartz on the /quartz endpoint. Can you point me to some information about how to get the quartz endpoint setup?

Comment: I just did, it's the same link. You can use that service or host it yourself.

Comment: updated link to the doc: https://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/scheduling/